# Azure Application Insights metrics drill down

Tags: metrics, azure-application-insights

I'm doing a proof of concept about Azure Insights. Now I'm evaluating custom metrics, and I've sent some metrics via C# code, and I have this question:  **How can I have sub-metrics (indentation) to drill down over their values?** For example a metric called "customer sales" showing sales by "region" (region as a property), and that metric could have associated information as follows:

---

Metric name: "Customer sales"
Metric value: 100.000
Property name: "region"
Property value:  South America > Colombia > Pacific > Chocó

---

Metric name: "Customer sales"
Metric value: 70.000
Property name: "region"
Property value:  South America > Colombia > Pacific > Cauca

---

Metric name: "Customer sales"
Metric value: 130.000
Property name: "region"
Property value:  South America > Colombia > Andean > Cundinamarca

---

I would like for example to:

- See sum of Colombia sales in a "bar chart" and I expect to see 300.000 as a chart value.
- See sum of Colombia > Pacific sales in a "bar chart" and I expect to see 170.000 as a chart value.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the aggregation charts by wildcarded values is not supported, so the scenario you are describing is not possible today. You can however try to use search explorer on Azure App insights and search for "Property Name": " Value*" and then apply appropriate filters to see the count and a timeline chart of values you are expecting.
[image]